# Are win-lose numbers the total wins of solo/duo and team ranked games combined?

Tags: league-of-legends

Question is straight forward. I have this in "profile -> leagues -> my leagues -> see more stats":

[image]

Now, is this the total amount of wins and loses of both ranked queues: solo/duo and team games? Or these are only from solo/duo queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers you see here are for **all ranked games**.

This means solqueue, ranked 5v5 play and ranked 3v3 play all count towards this statistic.

If you win 9 games in ranked 5v5 soloqueue with udyr and you lose one in 3v3 ranked your statistic will show a 90% winrate since every game counts.